# Collecting data from a random generated label collection

Tags: xcode, random, collections, label, information-retrieval

I am generating these tables made from random labels based on data arrays:

```
label1.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label2.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label3.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label4.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label5.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label6.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label7.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label8.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label9.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label10.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label11.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label12.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label13.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label14.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
label15.text = quizBrain.cities.randomElement()
```

There are 15 randoms labels being generated but I need to capture the data being displayed to be able to ask questions relating to such data that is being displayed only temporarily and generate appropriate questions.

Can I do that using UserDefaults? or what is the best way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "capture" the data, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when the table is generated from the array I need to know how many times each item from he array appears on the screen. basically it is a memory game. based on how many times each item appears on the screen the idea is to generate some questions, so I need to have that count to be able to generarte those. hope I am making myself clear.